# Theater Seats Average Price per Row

Tags: java

I'm working on a project in which I need to find the average price per seat for each row. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and I'm getting mildly frustrated. Here's my code so far I can answer questions about anything in my code if needed! There's a separate class called "seats" and my runner is called TheaterRunner.

```
public double[] averageSeatPriceByRow() {
     double[] prices = new double[20];
     int count = 0;
     int price = 0;
     for(int r = 0; r < seats.length; r++){
       for (int i = 0; i < prices.length; i++){
         for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++){
           price += seats[r][c].getPrice();
         }
         prices[i] = price / 8;
       }
     }
     return prices;
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: Start by splitting your method into two: one that loops through all the rows, and calls the second, computing the average price for a single given row.

Comment: Also, consider whether `int` is the best data type for storing a `price` in.  I'm worried that you'll lose the cents when you divide by 8.  I would suggest learning to use `BigDecimal`.